# angular2 add custom header to POST request

Tags: angular, cors, angular-http

I'm submitting a request to an API via POST for some data, but I keep getting the error `request header field UniqueClientID is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response`

This header is added to the request specifically, but CORS preflight options request is blocking it. How do I allow this header in the request and response?

Here's my function call

```
fetchReservation(reservationID: number) {
    let URI = `${AppService.API_URI}${AppService.MOBILE_PATH}${AppService.PROPERTY_ID}/reservation/${reservationID}`;
    let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + AppService.AUTH_TOKEN);
    headers.append('UniqueClientID', '0');

    return this._http.post(URI, '', { headers: headers })
      // ...and calling .json() on the response to return data
      .map((res: Response) => res)
      //...errors if any
      .catch(this._errorHandler);
  }
```

The API is running a .NET backend, and all CORS requests are enabled via `[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]` All `GET` requests are working fine

Answer (score 0):

In your backend you should allow access, here goes a PHP example:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');
header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');
```

If you don't allow Cross domain in your backend, you won't get access to it.

Hope it helped! ;)

Comment: Cross domain is enabled, and CORS is working for GET requests. The issue is with the POST requests

Answer (score 0):

Whatever technology you are using for server side development. In each response you must include response headers like **`UniqueClientID`** from server side

Answer (score 0):

response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST');

response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-Requested-With, content-type, access-control-allow-origin, access-control-allow-methods, access-control-allow-headers');

response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

Hack:-

If you are running it on chrome, you can also disable it via following command:-

Open Run -->

chrome.exe --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security

Browse on the opened window. I hope you will be able to run the application via this.

Comment: I'm looking to start the deployment process, and I need to fix this rather than hack around it. this does work though